# How to take Lotus Notes Event Calendar data From the Domino Server?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

i am new to programing..I need code for how to take lotus notes event calendar data from the domino server using C# and also i need to retrive that data on the aspx.cs web page.please can anybody help me....

Answer (score 1):

This site may get you started.  It shows code on how to add a calendar entry in Notes.  If nothing else, it shows you the general idea of how to connect to a Notes database from C#.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/130179/How-to-Add-a-Lotus-Notes-Calendar-Entry-with-Cshar.aspx